# two ints in java have the same value but are returning false when '==' operator is used

Tags: java, integer, awtrobot

```
  trueloop:
        while(true){
            for (Point p : getListcolor(244,238,215))
            {
                robot.mouseMove(p.x + 35, p.y + 165);
                if (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x == (p.x + 35) && MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y == (p.y + 165))
                {
                    robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                    robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
                    Thread.sleep(5);
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + ":" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + " " + (p.x + 35) + ":" + (p.y +165));
                    System.out.print("\rBreaking...");
                    break trueloop;
                }
            }
        }
```

this code is a failsafe for the java robot class, it checks to make sure whether the cursor has been manually moved.

MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x is the x coordinate of where the cursor is, and (p.x + 35) is where the cursor should be, and the same for y. But when these are compared it often returns false even if the two values are the same.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + ":" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + " " + (p.x + 35) + ":" + (p.y +165))` what is this printing?

Comment: What makes you think that the two values are the same?

Comment: @tgdavies i know the two values are the same because in the else statement it prints the values of both of them to the console

`System.out.println(MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x + ":" + MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y + " " + (p.x + 35) + ":" + (p.y +165));`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca that line prints both of the values (to check that they were both the same)

Comment: Instead of calling `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()` multiple times, call it once after `robot.mouseMove(...` and store the `Point`.